# C, get unsigned char to use ascii 2 table

Tags: c, arrays, char, ascii

so all i want is to get this to display the ascii 2 table using an unsigned char array.  heres what i have and whats not working:

```
unsigned char digits[100];
int i=0;
while (i<=100)
{
printf("\n%c",digits[i]+48);
i++;
}
```

pretty simple code so far.  not working at all though.

any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is an "ascii 2 table"? What does the "2" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `digits[i]` is not initialized.

If all you're doing is displaying the ASCII table, you don't need the array at all.

Comment: what i have to do is enter a large number in, and be able to use the an unsignec char array to say what that number is.  so if the number were 1234, i would go through each digit, saying the first digit is 4, so i go display 4 using the unsigned char array and so on...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use an array. This will work:

```
int i=0;
while (i<=100){
    printf("\n%c", i + '0');
    i++;
}
```

Also, your array is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char digits[100] = { 1,0,2,4 };
    int i=0;

    while (i<100){
        printf("\n%c",digits[i++]+'0');
    }

    printf("\ninput number:");
    fgets(digits, 100, stdin);

    i=0;
    while(digits[i] && digits[i] != '\n')
        printf("\n%c", digits[i++]);

    return 0;
}
```